# Restrict access to woocommerce checkout with php cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

In an attempt to solving this problem [Guest checkout button on checkout redirect page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70761239/guest-checkout-button-on-checkout-redirect-page) ,

I'm trying to let the checkout be accessed **only** when a cookie is set with php. The cookie gets set from on a custom login page. If the cookie is set, continue displaying the page. If not, redirect.

On my custom login page i have:

```
<?php
setcookie("custom_login", 1);
?>
```

And on the woocommerce checkout template I have:

```
<?php
if (isset($COOKIE["custom_login"]))
{ 
// do nothing 
} else {
// redirect to custom login
header('Location: checkout-redirect');
exit;
}
?>
```

I can see that the cookie is being set, however it ignores the first condition and always redirects to the custom login page. What am I doing wrong?